# Cannot update entity using Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using Hibernate with JPA annotated entities and the next code which I expect to update "`raw_text`" field of an entity doesn't change it. How to achieve the expected behavior?

```
@Override
public void updatePageWithText(String pageName, String rawText) {
     Session session = HibernateUtils.getInstance().openSession();
     String hql = "FROM WikiPage M WHERE M.name = :name";
     Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
     query.setParameter("name",pageName);

     WikiPage res = null;
     try {
         res = (WikiPage) query.list().get(0);
         res.setRawText(rawText);
         session.update(res);
         session.flush();
     }
     catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {}
     finally {
         session.close();
     }

}
```

Comment: AFAIK you should open a transaction and commit it before closing the session.

Comment: How do you know that you're not getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
@Override
public void updatePageWithText(String pageName, String rawText) {
     Session session = HibernateUtils.getInstance().openSession();
     Transaction transaction=session.beginTransaction();
     String hql = "FROM WikiPage M WHERE M.name = :name";
     Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
     query.setParameter("name",pageName);

     WikiPage res = null;
     try {
         res = (WikiPage) query.list().get(0);
         res.setRawText(rawText);
         transaction.commit();
     }
     catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
         transaction.rollback();
     }
     finally {
         session.close();
     }

}
```

`Note :` When you get WikiPage from query, it's still an attached entity so you do not need to fire `session.update()`, `committing`  the `transaction` would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The update must be inside of a transaction, which must be commited before the session is closed (or rolled back in the case of an error). Try it with the following code:

```
    @Override
public void updatePageWithText(String pageName, String rawText) {
    Session session = null;
    Transaction tx = null;

    WikiPage res = null;

    try {
        session = HibernateUtils.getInstance().openSession();
        tx = session.beginTransaction();

        String hql = "FROM WikiPage M WHERE M.name = :name";
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        query.setParameter("name",pageName);
        res = (WikiPage) query.list().get(0);
        res.setRawText(rawText);
        session.update(res);

        tx.commit;
    }
    catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {}
    catch (Exception ex) {
        if (tx!=null) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
        throw ex;
    }
    finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Under the following link you can find more about transaction handling in hibernate (in the case of a non-managed context which is probably your case): https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-demarcation-nonmanaged

Answer (score 1):

u can also user annotation @query with @Modifying to define interface in repository.

```
@Modifying
@Query(" UPDATE WikiPage w set name = :name ")
public void updateName(@Param("name")String name);
```

more details in Jpa Repsitory(http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.6.4.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html), chapter 2.3.7 Modifying queries